# Thymeleaf takes too long to process the template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

guys !
I notices that from time to time, my response is generated about approx. 10 sec. which is not normal. This normally happens when i submit a post form, but not always. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 with Thymeleaf 3.0.2.

```
2017-10-16 09:09:21.737 TRACE 19366 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] o.t.s.e.LinkExpression                   : [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] Evaluating link: "@{'/resources/js/lightbox.js'}"
2017-10-16 09:09:21.737 TRACE 19366 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] o.t.s.e.TextLiteralExpression            : [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] Evaluating text literal: "'/resources/js/lightbox.js'"
2017-10-16 09:09:21.737 TRACE 19366 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] o.t.TemplateEngine                       : [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] FINISHED PROCESS AND OUTPUT OF TEMPLATE "distributor/createDistributor" WITH LOCALE en_US
2017-10-16 09:09:21.737 TRACE 19366 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] o.t.T.TIMER                              : [THYMELEAF][https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1][distributor/createDistributor][en_US][8336337999][8336] TEMPLATE "distributor/createDistributor" WITH LOCALE en_US PROCESSED IN 8336337999 nanoseconds (approx. 8336ms)
2017-10-16 09:09:21.738 TRACE 19366 --- [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1c6b6478: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/distributor/add]; client=[192........]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[F2E366C8DA7EC3C5BD2026FA388F3437]; user=[admin]; time=[8338ms]; status=[OK]
```

On line 4 ( TIMER ) is showing that processing time is time=[8338ms]

Can somebody help me how to debug this ?

Comment: For starters disable TRACE logging (logging really slows down your application).

Comment: This is only for debbugin ... it is not enabled in production

Comment: do you get javascript from external resources? Maybe this could be a problem.

Comment: I have only one external resource ( bootstrap-select from CDN ) I don't think that thisi s the problem.

Comment: Also a POST are you sure it is thymeleaf or your backend that is taking that long to process.

Comment: It should be Thymeleaf, because when i test the form with empty fields, the form is returned with errors from the validation. That means that there is no interaction with the database.

  if(results.hasErrors()){
   return "distributor/createDistributor";
  }